# Problemas al generar reportes con JasperReport desde la .jar

Tags: java

Buenas noches tengo un problema en donde en el ide de netbeans genero los reportes sin problemas pero al generar la .jar y al intentarlo me sale la excepcion java.io.filenotfoundexception aun soy nuevo en esto pero quisiera solucionar el problema

```
public void generarReporte(){
    try{
        ConexionSoloParaReportes con=new ConexionSoloParaReportes();
        Connection connn=con.getConexion();
        JasperReport reporte=null;
        String path="src\\ReportesSQL\\ReporteProfesor.jasper";
        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(path);
        JasperPrint jprint =JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,null,connn);
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint,false);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        view.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

La excepcion que me genera al intentar generar  el reporte ya desde el .jar es
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\ReportesSQL\ReporteProfesor.jasper

Comment: Será porque Jasper reports genera archivos .jrxml y .jasper pero no .jar

Comment: Me refiero que cuando genero la .jar de mi programa y a la hora de generar el reporte me sale Java.io.filenotfoundexception

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ESPERO TE SIRVA
try {

```
        Conexion co = new Conexion();
        Connection cnn = co.getConexion();
        JasperReport reporte = null;
        String path = "src/reportes/Prueba.jasper";

        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put("cod_venta", reVenta);

        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("/reportes/Prueba.jasper"));
        JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, param, cnn);
        JasperViewer view = new JasperViewer(jprint, false);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        view.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Recuerda que la respuesta no es solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].

Comment: Muchas gracias aunque mi solución ya la tenia desde hace tiempo pero literalmente es la misma que hice en su momento!

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente es problema de la ruta, al estar en NetBeans funciona bien con la ruta relativa pero un .jar trabaja rutas independientes. Recuerda que la idea es poder ejecutarlo en cualquier pc.

Puedes cargarlos a través de getSystemResourceAsStream algo así:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("com/foo/blah/reports/myreport.jasper"),parametros, etc...
```

Comment: aun no me deja, sigo intentando con otra forma pero me genera error

Answer (score 0):

Lo estas generando con Maven o como estas trabajando el proyecto.

Este error puede salir cuando no encuentra las fuentes a la hora de compilar el Jasper, por lo que debes tener en la carpeta lib el Jar con las fuentes, existe documentación para hacerlo, e importas ese Jar en la configuración del proyecto.

Una solución parcial, es implementar en el **pom.xml** la siguiente dependencia.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se debía hacer, era especificar la ruta donde se encontraban tus reportes en la raiz de tu .jar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo
//Fragmento del código para llamar el reporte

```
JasperReport report = null;
        File ruta = new File("src/Reportes/mireporte.jasper");



introducir el código aquí
```